# hi i m trying to find all the prime numbers from 1 to 1000 and find their max diffirence

Tags: python, python-2.7

I already got the following part and  I think its a fast and clear way and I dont need it to be faster:

```
for num in range(2,1000):
    if all(num%i!=0 for i in range(2,num)):
       print num
```

**But how can I find the max difference of all the prime numbers I got and put that as the final result?**

Comment: The max difference in this case is just the last prime minus the first prime

Comment: Do you mean the maximum difference between two *consecutive* primes?

Comment: yeah the last minus the first prime but how can i find it? should i put them in a list and do it with the 0 and -1 spot of the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can proceed like that:

```
biggest_prime = 2
for num in range(2,1000):
    if all(num%i!=0 for i in range(2,num)):
      biggest_prime = num
print "Difference: " + str(biggest_prime - 2) # outputs 995
```

Basically, you just store the last found prime, and when you're out of the loop you will have the value of the highest prime below 1000. You can then substract 2 to it.

If you don't like the fact that the `2`is hard-coded, you can add a second variable `lowest_prime` that will change value only once.

Comment: Shouldn't you start counting *backwards* from 1000 so you only have to compute a single prime?

Comment: @user3483203 Well, yes. But he said he didn't need it to be any faster so I didn't touch it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't output each prime; store it in a list, so that once you have the full list, you can do what you like with the primes.

```
primes = []
for num in range(2, 1000):
    if all(num % i != 0 for i in range(2, num)):
        primes.append(num)
```

More briefly,

```
primes = [num for num in range(2, 1000) if all(num % i != 0 for i in range(2, num)]
```

Comment: alright then i use the first and last spot of the list to find the max difference right?

Comment: If that's what you mean by the maximum difference, yes.

Answer (score 0):

```
primes = []
for num in range(2, 1000):
    if all(num % i != 0 for i in range(2, num)):
        primes.append(num)
x = primes[-1] - primes[0]
print(x)
```

so is this okay?